# Error: Cannot access field element on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<element STRING>> in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I exported a df from pyspark to BigQuery. The df has columns with array elements, how can i convert the arrays into concatenated string ? Whenever i try to query the array column of the exported BigQuery table, i get the below error.

```
Error: Cannot access field element on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<element STRING>>
```

Below is the df in pyspark which was exported to BigQuery:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
| antecedent|consequent|         confidence|              lift|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|[19, 6, 39]|      [44]|  0.418945963975984|10.602038775664845|
|[19, 6, 39]|      [35]|0.47298198799199465| 7.423073393311932|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [322]|   0.47631754503002|4.6520592549063995|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [308]| 0.4496330887258172| 5.856259667533207|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [345]| 0.5196797865243495|5.4970336458402285|
```

Below is the schema of the table in BigQuery which was generated after exporting the df from pyspark to bigquery:

[image]

When viewed as a table this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: provide the SQL statement of your query, so we can fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/135) when using parquet as intermediate format to write to BigQuery. Can you please switch to ORC? The way to do it is:

```
df.write.format("bigquery").option("table","...").option("temporaryGcsBucket","...").option("intermediateFormat","orc").save()
```

Comment: Also, for some reason it's takes a really long time to write df to bigquery and at times even terminates before the action is completed. Is there a way to optimize it ?